# Isolated Switch

Tags: opto-isolator, protection, isolation

I have three question on designing Isolated switch (Protected Microcontroller and from accidentally inserting power)

1. Does it matter which side is the switch -  on 15V(Isolated side) (image 1) side or Ground side(image2)
2. Do I need add cap to 1K to create low pass filter to protect from noise
3. Do I need diode for over voltage or the Optoisolator diode is enouph.

Image 1: Switch on 15V side (Customer have access to 15V supply)

[image]

Image 2: Switch on Ground side   (Customer have access to Isolated GND )
[image]

- Keep in mind 15V isolated will be shared with other circuits too

Comment: Other than dots, what is the difference between the images? If your circuit contains 24V, why do the images show 15V? (Perhaps you should use the schematic editor instead of posting unrelated pictures?)

Comment: I think we need a lot more information. Why do you care what the "customer" can access? What does the optoisolator output connect to and how exactly is that signal used? Why is overvoltage a risk, and what is the maximum possible input voltage on the LED side?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Customer have access to this switch by terminal blocks and  shorting the it will activate something.  In past customer insert DC or Ac power in the terminal block and blow the circuit.

Comment: @JYelton Sorry I draw this circuit on falstad.com on but I wrote wrong voltage on stack overflow will be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, it doesn't matter if you switch the low side or high side.  Convention is to switch the high side.
2. Depends on how much noise you are talking about.  The LED in the opto-isolator requires very little voltage to light up, so power would have to almost completely drop out.  Likely you don't need a capacitor.  TODO: check that 1K resistor doesn't allow too much current on LED at 15V.

Comment: Thanks for your comment (I have updated the resistor)

Comment: If the LED drops 2v, and is supplied with 15V, then 13V must drop across the resistor.  13V/390Ω = 33mA.  Will this opto tolerate 33mA?  And 33mA * 13V = 0.433W, so must be at least 1W rated.

Comment: Hmmm.  You changed the 1k -> 390 ohm.  I would expect a value like 4.7k or 10k.  Check the optoisolator spec sheet for minimum and max current on that LED.

Comment: @Mr_Engineer I am using LTV-846S which have VF = 1.2 so if  We go with If= 20mA=> (13-1.2)/0.02 = 690ohm =>

Comment: @Shahreza 20mA is reasonable but may shorten the life of the optoisolator.  Will it work properly at 10mA?

Comment: According to Mouser LTV-846S has a CTR (current transfer ratio) of 600, so even 1mA across the input side would result in a collector current of theoretically 600mA but in reality 50mA max.  You could safely use a 10K resistor.  I would lean towards 4.7k for the extra margin.

Answer (score 1):

Either way can work but there may be advantages to one or the other depending upon the specific situation.

For example in cars it is common to use a grounded switch (eg brake lights or dome light) as it doesn't require that the positive supply be connected to the switch. This saves a wire as the ground is available everywhere in a car by means of the chassis. In your case it may also avoid the need for the +15V to be provided to the customer. The +15V that goes outside your unit will need protecting in-case the customer accidentally shorts it to ground or another supply.

However high-side switching might be used if the +15V was already available outside your unit and existing signals are already active-high.